# Video.js IE combatibility SWF wont work?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using video.js and it just wont work on IE. I have included the swf file this way:

```
videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.swf "
```

And this is the code for the video player

```
<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls preload="none" width="760" height="433"
    data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
    <source src="img/0.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="img/0.webmhd.webm" type='.webmhd.webm' />
    <source src="img/0.oggtheora.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

the mp4 file is with a h.264 encoding.

Anyone knows what might be the problem? If I need to include more code in this message let me know!
Thanks alot!

Comment: Please specify which version of IE and video.js you are using..

Comment: It should work on 9+ and I am using the latest version of video.js

Answer (score 0):

For IE9

First you need to Put

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

in header, and using

```
 <video id="my_video_1_ie" class="video-js vjs-default-skin video-ie9" controls preload="none" width="478" height="358" poster="......">
       <source src="....." type='video/mp4' /> 
 </video>
```

and only including mp4 format for it.

and I have another video tag embed

```
 <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin video-ie9" controls preload="none" width="478" height="358" poster="......">
       <source src="....." type='video/mp4' /> 
 </video> 

 <script> 
  _V_("my_video_1"); 
 </script>.
```

Then using conditional comment to including a style sheet for ie9 to 
hide/show the video.

It is wired to solve it like this, and takes more bandwidth, so it is 
better to turn off the auto load.

Source: [Video.js Forum](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1636-video-player-not-working-in-ie)